# How to cross out text through button click with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hey I want to do a checklist, if you click on the check button, the line should be crossed out.

By now I figured the decoration out to which the Textstyle should change. I have now two problems I don't really know how to add the button in the body of the list tile, next to the text & I don't really understand how I could add the button functionality

```
style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough))
```

This is the relevant code

```
body: ListTile(
      title: Text(info.expandedValue, //here should the textstyle change based on the click
      ),
      subtitle: Text("Drücke auf den Mülleimer, um diesen Abschnitt bis zum Neustart der App zu löschen"),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          infos.removeWhere((currentInfo) => info ==currentInfo);
        });
      },
    ),
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: You have to wrap your listTile and a flatbutton inside a Row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your model has some boolean attribute completed you could use a ListTile witha  CheckBox.

```dart
 ListTile(
          leading: Checkbox(
            value: info.completed,
            onChanged: (value) {

        setState(() {
// Here you toggle the checked item state
          infos.firstWhere((currentInfo) => info==currentInfo)..completed=value;
        });}
          ),
          title:  Text(info.description,
style: TextStyle(decoration: info.completed?TextDecoration.lineThrough:null))),
        ),
```

Comment: Hey worked all fine, but is there any way to move the checkbox?, I need it to be slightly higher

Comment: Sure @Nikita , try wrapping your checkbox in a Padding and adding some at the bottom. Or use a Row(instead of a ListTile) with the Checkbox and Text wrapped in Expanded as children that way you have more control over the layout.

Comment: Thanks! One last thing, Im currently trying to add another regular List, into the extended part, didn't quiet work, do you know how to add another list into the extendable part of the tile?

Comment: Hey @Nikita probably that should be a different question . If so mark this question as answered and put a link to the next question.

Comment: You are right, hope the link works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67839054/how-to-add-a-regular-list-view-in-the-extended-part-of-an-extendable-list-view